# Python ttk Scrollbar error as child of Toplevel(), but works as child of Tk()

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have taken a code example from the web which works as a child of the root window created as Tk(). When i tried to generalize it for my purpose as child of Toplevel(), i get an error indicating that you can't put the scrollbar into the Toplevel().Frame(). I can not figure out why the difference since Tk() and Toplevel() are supposed to yield similar results.

The exact error message is:

> _tkinter.TclError: can't put .19084144 inside .18651952.19084112
>     or... can't put scrollbar inside Toplevel().Frame()

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class columnList(object):
    def __init__(self,parent,header,dataList):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets(parent,header)
        self._build_tree(header,dataList)

    def _setup_widgets(self,parent,header):
        treeFrame = Frame(parent)
        treeFrame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        # create a treeview with a vertical scrollbar
        self.tree = Treeview(treeFrame, columns=header, show="headings")
        vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical",command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=treeFrame)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=treeFrame)
        treeFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        treeFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self,header,dataList):
        for col in header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
        for item in dataList:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
# the test data ...
oil_header = ['oil', 'filter', 'cost']
oil_list = [
('synthetic', 'paper', '63.38') ,
('natural', 'reusable', '47.59') ]
car_header = ['car', 'repair', 'cost', 'code']
car_list = [
('Hyundai', 'brakes', '273.80', '34') ,
('Honda', 'light', '85.70', '78')]

root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()

# this succeeds
invoiceMenu = columnList(root,car_header,car_list)
# this fails as
# _tkinter.TclError: can't put .19084144 inside .18651952.19084112
#   or... can't put scrollbar inside Toplevel().Frame()
oilChangeMenu = columnList(top,oil_header,oil_list)
root.mainloop()
```

I have used stackoverflow extensively to learn a great deal and very much appreciate the incredible wealth of expertise that is here. Frankly, i'm embarassed that i could not figure this one out. Thank you in anticipation of any help you can provide.

Comment: can you show the line of code that gives the exact error you are reporting? I'm not sure I see any code that would give that error. Plus, a line of code will only give a single error, so it's unclear what you mean when you say it gives one of two different errors. Showing an exact stack trace may help.

Comment: @BryanOakley that is exactly it. The corrected line of code is

`vsb = Scrollbar(parent,orient="vertical",command=self.tree.yview)`

I do feel humbled (and foolish).
I will take this opportunity to mention, Bryan, that your responses have done more to help me (and others) than one could express sufficient appreciation for. Thank you, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough detail in your question to know for certain, but the problem likely stems from the fact you aren't giving a `parent` argument when you create the scrollbar. This means that the scrollbar will always be created in the root window. If you then try to place it in another toplevel, you'll get an error similar to what you report.